# Obtaining data sets for solved murder

Tags: data-request, usa, uk, crime

Ii'd like to do a research project & developing an application which requires a data set of solved murders. Ideally containing: Something unique to the case, like an ID. Solved / unsolved and a description.

Does anyone know if anything like this exists for the UK / USA.

I've tried some Googling and couldn't really find much which really suits the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Kaggle hosts the [Homicide Reports](https://www.kaggle.com/murderaccountability/homicide-reports) dataset

> The Murder Accountability Project is the most complete database of homicides in the United States currently available. This dataset includes murders from the FBI's Supplementary Homicide Report from 1976 to the present and Freedom of Information Act data on more than 22,000 homicides that were not reported to the Justice Department. This dataset includes the age, race, sex, ethnicity of victims and perpetrators, in addition to the relationship between the victim and perpetrator and weapon used.

Data comes from one CSV and has a nice, easy-to-use data model.

[image]