# Unsolved murder rates by country/state/municipality

Tags: data-request, crime

I have read on [Hacker News today](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=14331880) that

> The overall solution rate for murder in the US is about 65%. In big cities with dubious police leadership, the solution rate for murder can be under 50%.

<sub>(Chicago, Baltimore, St.Lou etc..., right?)</sub>

Where can one get the dataset for the States, and for other countries of the world, at any level of aggregation?

Yes, I do know about police misreporting, and forced confessions. Having both corrected and raw rates would be great.

The narrowest definition is finding the victim's body. Rate of unsolved disappearance cases would be a welcome, but not essential variable.

Similar questions here:

- [Where can I find adult abduction victim statistics for the United States?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/5069/where-can-i-find-adult-abduction-victim-statistics-for-the-united-states) (a somewhat different crime, unanswered)
- [Obtaining data sets for solved murder](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/9690/obtaining-data-sets-for-solved-murder) (the question asks for a micro dataset, is unanswered, and I want a geographically aggregated one)

P.S. Use case - should be an excellent indicator of rule of law/lawlessness in an area.

Comment: look at the geographies available in the national crime and victimization survey?

Comment: BTW, lower "solution" rates in big cities might simply be because there are more possible suspects and/or more places to hide the bodies. Watch out for statistical speculation: it can be very wrong.

Answer (score 3):

The Uniform Crime Report program will have the best answer to your question for the U.S.  The best known part of this program is the annual report "Crime in the United States" issued by the FBI every fall.  That's the source of most of your crime rate information reported in the popular press.
What you're looking for is the clearance rate -- which is not quite the same as a solved case, but is very close.
There is no way to get clearance information at a department/local level from the mainstream reports.  That data is archived at the ICPSR, a social research repository at the University of Michigan. 
Here's a link to the latest raw data - https://www.icpsr.umich.edu/icpsrweb/ICPSR/series/57 - it's from 2015.

Answer (score 1):

Kaggle has a [Murder Accountability dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/murderaccountability/homicide-reports) you may find useful.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, it is quite easy to find some open historical data. For example:

- [County Characteristics, 2000-2007 [United States] (ICPSR 20660)](http://www.icpsr.umich.edu/icpsrweb/NACJD/studies/20660)
- [Valuation of Specific Crime Rates in the United States, 1980 and 1990 (ICPSR 3161)](http://www.icpsr.umich.edu/icpsrweb/NACJD/studies/3161)